# Inconsistency with multiplication of different size of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, orthogonal-matrices

I am a little confused about the following:

Let **A** be an $\mathbb{R}^{n \times f}$ matrix, **B** be an $\mathbb{R}^{m \times f}$ matrix, and **C** be an $\mathbb{R}^{f \times d}$ orthogonal matrix. If $f > d$, then $A B^T \neq (A C) (B C)^T$. However, whenever $d \leq f$, the statement becomes true, i.e. $A B^T = (A C) (B C)^T$.

I probably miss a very straightforward property here since I have still a lot to learn in linear algebra. I would appreciate it if you can help me figure out the underlying reason here.

Thanks.

Comment: An orthogonal matrix is a _square_ matrix.

Comment: That's quite right. I totally miss it. Thanks.